# Open Layers change Z Axis orientation

Tags: openlayers

I would like change the direction of the elevation or z axis to point up on the screen rather than out of the screen.  Does anyone know of anyway to do this for Points that have X, Y, Z coordinates?  Short of faking out Openlayers and changing X <==> Z of the actual points, prior to adding them to the source/layer?

Comment: Note: Z is used for zoom not elevation. (Openlayer display just 2D maps). X, Y are just coordinated of the image. If you interpret x as latitude, longitude or altitude is up to you (and your images). So you may need to handle it into your data.

Comment: I presume you are referring to OpenLayers XYZ geometry layout https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_GeometryLayout.html where  Z is used to represent elevation in KML and GPX sources.  Z is not an axis on a flat map, but if you are displaying vector points it can be easily represented by scaling the style https://codesandbox.io/s/kml-forked-g31qs?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses.  I think you have confirmed what I thought, Openlayers is strictly 2D.  It looks like we'll have to transpose the data ourselves. -Thanks